# How to record performance of a glmnet model on a new dataset

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, glmnet

I used cv.glmnet to create a model using one dataset ("Dataset 1"), but now I would like to look at performance (e.g., AUC) when predicting outcomes for new data ("Dataset 2"). I know that I can use predict.glmnet to predict new data, but the output is just a list of predicted outcomes for each observation in Dataset 2. **How do I actually summarize the predictive *performance* (e.g., AUC) of a cv.glmnet model on on Dataset 2?**

For example, it would be nice to be able to save the predictions for Dataset 2 as a new column. From there I can just calculate performance myself manually, but ideally I'd like to know if there is a way to have these indices calculated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using the pROC library in R:

```
labels = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0)
pred = c(.1,.1,.3,0,0.1,.6,0.2,.8,0)

library(pROC)
auc(roc(labels, pred))
```

returns

```
Area under the curve: 0.85
```

source: https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/11/calculating-auc.html

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I have a harder time finding answers to the simplest problems than more complex ones.